# Chrome doesn't show empty anchor tag

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

**Problem:**
Chrome appears to not visibly render an empty anchor tag with a left padding and background color when the anchor tag is inside of a span and there is a whitespace character between the text inside the span and the anchor tag.

If the whitespace is removed from between the span's text and the nested anchor tag, the anchor tag renders as expected. This

This appears to only affect chrome. I've confirmed the tag renders in IE and FF but haven't tried Safari.

**Mark Up:**

```
<span id="container1">asd <a></a></span>
<br/>
<span id="container2">asd<a></a></span>
```

**Style:**

```
#container1 a, #container2 a{
    padding-left:17px;
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/98ezf/1/

The markup is being generated by pagedown.

How can I force chrome to render the anchor tag nested in #container1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline` elements can't have padding. `a` is `display: inline` by default. Change it to `inline-block`. You'll also need to specify a height or it will be `0px` tall, i.e.: invisible.

```
#container1 a, #container2 a{
    padding-left:17px;
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em; /* or whatever */
}
```

Here's a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/zZ493/1).

[image: output]

Comment: I don't know. I'm actually surprised they don't all work like chrome.

Comment: Technically he did answer your question. You should mark this as correct. If you want to dig deeper, open another question.

Comment: @justnS Just differences of opinion in how CSS properties should be implemented, I imagine. Or it's possible that IE and FF's implementations are only the same by coincidence.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your input. I'm sure you are aware SO requires a small window of time to pass before an answer can be accepted. I accepted the answer the exact second I was able to.